# Skipping validation phase but need to update model values

Tags: java, validation, jsf, icefaces

JSF code.
`<ice:inputText id="txtemailFrom" required="true"
 requiredMessage="please enter proper value in From Address field" value="#{emailBean1.sender}" maxlength="100" size="40">
    <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
</ice:inputText>`

```
<ice:selectOneRadio id="emailType" 
                value="#{emailBean1.currentEmailType}"
                valueChangeListener="#{emailBean1.onEmailTypeChange}"
                partialSubmit="true"
                style="margin-left:95px">

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Do Not Reply" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="User's Email" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Custom Email" />

            </ice:selectOneRadio>
```

java code for validator:

```
public void onEmailTypeChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

    logger.debug(new LogEntry(" EmailBean.onEmailTypeChange() execution is started."));
    String emailType = event.getNewValue().toString();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.setUserEmailId(roleHandler.getUserId() + "@xxx.com");
    HtmlInputText txtComponent = (HtmlInputText) Utils.findComponent(
            context.getViewRoot(), "txtemailFrom");

    if (emailType.equals("Do Not Reply")) {
        this.setEmailFrom("donotreply@fedex.com");
        txtComponent.setValue("donotreply@fedex.com");
    } else if (emailType.equals("User's Email")) {
        this.setEmailFrom(this.getUserEmailId());
        txtComponent.setValue(this.getUserEmailId());
    } else if(emailType.equals("Custom Email")){
        this.setEmailFrom("");
        txtComponent.setValue("");
    }
    logger.debug(new LogEntry(
            " EmailBean.onEmailTypeChange() execution is ended."));
}
```

when i am changing the radio button values it is updating the value in inputTextField of fromEmailaddress.  i am updating value via java by using this code.

```
HtmlInputText txtComponent = (HtmlInputText) Utils.findComponent(
            context.getViewRoot(), "txtemailFrom");
```

but my issue is like i am using validator for the inputtext field when i change the radio button and if the email in invalid then its failing and showing error message.. it works as per jsf approach but as per my requirement it should change the value in email inputTextFied.. i tried immediate="true" then its skipping validation phase but its not updating the values into the Emailtextfield.

Comment: please comment it if my explanation is not sufficient

Comment: dont share the client details "@fedex.com" ;)

Comment: is onEmailTypeChange the validator you are mentioning ?

Comment: No this is  valueChangListener i mentioned in the code

Comment: can you try putting an ajax tag inside <ice:selectOneRadio ? if ajax not supported you can use normal jsf radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try using Immediate='true' in the check box.
If you put immediate='true' it will not validate the field and it will submit the values into server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom validator. Then you can update the model even before the validation occurs. Here a fragment of code that I use for the same purpose:

```
validate(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, Object val) {
    ValueExpression ve = ((UIInput) comp).getValueExpression("value");
    ve.setValue(ctx.getELContext(), val);
    // your validation logic...
}
```

Hope it helps!